# sqlite insert while drop complete duplicate

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite

I am crawling some website and store the results in sqlite, since my crawling may repeat every month, but I don't want to store the duplicate results in my database, what should I do?

For example, the first time I will

```
insert into tableName(A, B, C, D, E) values(a,b,c,d,e)
```

then my database will have this record, the next time I crawl this website, I will do the same, but I do not want to store the duplicate results, what is the best way I can do?

Besides, what to do if I am using MySQL?

Comment: What constitutes a duplicate record? Must all five values be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sqlite, [create your table with a UNIQUE constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html):

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (A INTEGER, B INTEGER, C INTEGER, D INTEGER, E INTEGER,
UNIQUE (A, B, C, D, E));
```

then

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tableName (A, B, C, D, E) values (a,b,c,d,e);
```

[will only insert a new record if `(a,b,c,d,e)` is unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15541535/190597) -- i.e. not already present in the table `tableName`.

To [add a UNIQUE index to an already existent table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9843229/190597):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_idx on tableName(A, B, C, D, E);
```

---

or, using MySQL, [create a table with a unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

```
CREATE TABLE tableName (A INT, B INT, C INT, D INT, E INT,
UNIQUE KEY unique_idx (A, B, C, D, E))
```

then [use INSERT IGNORE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/548541/190597):

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tableName (A, B, C, D, E) values (a,b,c,d,e)
```

To [add a UNIQUE KEY index to an already existent table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20116140/190597):

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD UNIQUE KEY unique_idx (A, B, C, D, E);
```

Comment: does each table have only one index or several?

Comment: One table can have several.

Comment: Thanks! another question, in this way, does it mean all A (or B or C..) needs to be unique?

Comment: No, it means the tuple (A,B,C,D,E) has to be unique. You can of course change the criteria...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insert ignore`

SQLite

```
insert or ignore into tableName(A, B, C, D, E) values(a,b,c,d,e)
```

MySQL

```
insert ignore into tableName(A, B, C, D, E) values(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Be carefull that the difference between the two code are the **or**, they are not the same.

This will only work if they have some kind of primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a temporary/auxiliary table say `temp_tableName`having same schema as `tableName`. Then while crawling perform like

```
insert into temp_tableName select * from tableName;

delete from tableName;

insert into tableName(A, B, C, D, E) values(a,b,c,d,e)
```

Auxiliary table is needed cause if the crawling insert fails then you have a back up to store from. Also, consider doing this steps `DELETE/INSERT` in a `Transaction` block for atomicity.

Comment: This helps, but is there anyway that I can just drop the duplicate if I found it is already in the table? My initial thought was to do select * from tableName where A=a, B=b, C=c, D=d, E=e and check whether there is such record. Is it a good way to do this?

Comment: Depends, If you are performing row/row insert then probably yes but would be bit costly. Since insert happens from crawler I believe it would be a bulk insert; answered keeping that in mind.